# If $(ord_m(a), ord_m(b)) = 1$ prove that $ord_m(ab) = ord_m(a)*ord_m(b) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-order

> $\DeclareMathOperator\ord{ord}$Let $a, b$, and $m$ be positive integers such that $(a,m) = (b,m) = 1$. Assume that $(\ord_m(a), \ord_m(b)) = 1$. Prove that $\ord_m(ab) = \ord_m(a)*\ord_m(b)$.

So I got $(ab)^{\ord_m(a)*\ord_m(b)} = 1 \bmod m$

so $\ord_m(ab) \mid \ord_m(a) * \ord_m(b)$.

I am stuck on how to proceed from here though.

Comment: Have you tried to show that $ord_m(a)\mid ord_m(ab)$?

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator\ord{ord}$Let $x=\ord_m(a)$, $y=\ord_m(b)$ and $z=\ord_m(ab)$. You already found that $z\mid xy$. It remains to prove that $xy\mid z$.

We have that
$$\begin{align}1&\equiv((ab)^z)^y\\
&=a^{zy}(b^y)^z\\
&\equiv a^{zy}.\end{align}$$
Therefore, $x\mid zy$. As $\gcd(x,y)=1$, it follows that $x\mid z$.

Analogously we can show that $y\mid z$. Because $\gcd(x,y)=1$, this means that $xy\mid z$, which completes the proof. $\square$